# Contact Form field not clickable on mobile - redirects to next field

Tags: html, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I've designed a contact form for my site that works properly on desktop. When trying to do some responsive programming, I realized that the first field in the form (Name) is not clickable. Clicking the button just takes you to the next field (Email). Anyone else experience this problem? It's happening on all mobile devices as far as I can tell.

The URL is envolverxlaunch.com and the form is on the bottom of the page.

Thanks!
Brandon

Answer (score 1):

Just checked the DOM with the Chrome Dev-Tools in mobile emulate mode, and I have found that input and label element off the name field lays under the input and label element off the mailaddress. It overlaps, because the first input element has a huge margin-bottom, and some elements are not cleared. If you click on the name field, you hit the label off the email field.